# Make a word list from any document in python

Tags: python, text, document, cpu-word

I am wanting to output a simple word list from any text document. I want every word listed but no duplicates. This is what I have but it doesn't do anything. I am fairly new to python. Thanks!

```
def MakeWordList():
    with open('text.txt','r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return set([word for wordd])
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Seeing you're trying to read from an `rtf` file, maybe you could start by having a look at all the words that are returned, without any filtering at first; what do you get? Also, instead of `islower()`, maybe you should use [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.isalpha)?

Comment: I edited it to what I am looking for. The code I posted was an example code I was using.

Comment: But now your sample code is nonsense :-/ Please provide what you have tried so far; here it doesn't even run.

Answer (score 2):

`for word in data` loop basically iterates over `data`, which is string, so your `word` loop variable gets a single character in each iteration. You would want to use something like `data.split()` to loop over the list of words.

Comment: Is this also applicable to `rtf` files? End of lines do not seem to be as simple as `\n` characters.

Comment: @Joël I would say yes. "If the separator is not specified, any whitespace (space, newline etc.) string is a separator." https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over the data you read like this, because they are a string so as a result you get consecutive characters, however you can split the string on spaces, which will give you a list of words

```
def MakeWordList():
    with open('possible.rtf','r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return set([word for word in data.split(' ') if len(word) >= 5 and word.islower() and not 'xx' in word])
```

Comment: `data.split(' ')` doesn't split on newline characters. You get some strange results like 'name\nand' where '\n' is the newline character.  It would seem @taras recommendation of `data.split()` would solve that issue.

Comment: It still doesn't print anything. 
def MakeWordList():
    with open('test.txt','r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return set([word for word in data.split()])

    print ()

Comment: `print()` does indeed not print anything. Try `print(MakeWordList())`.